# Cелектор при вызове функции на JS событии

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется конструкция вида

```
<div>
<p>Text</p>
<a onclick="Func()">Bla-Bla</a>
</div>
```

Можно ли передать функции `Func()` объект `div` без использования явных селекторов, т.е. как родителя?

Comment: можно, _this_ указывает на _a_ от него и считайте

Comment: простите об этом не подумал). Очень хотелось на вход функции сразу нужный объект подать)

Comment: ну так тут сразу объект и получите, или что вы имели ввиду _без использования явных селекторов_?

Comment: ссылкой this я естественно получаю объект <a>, думал может сразу можно и div передать

Comment: ну так и передайте `this.parentNode` - вполне себе див, который вы можете передать в функцию

Comment: `this.parentElement` должен вам помочь

Comment: Спасибо) Это и хотел услышать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения ссылки на родительский узел можно использовать свойство [*parentNode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

```
<a onclick="Func(this.parentNode)">Bla-Bla</a>
```